Confirming Application of LT1308
I am intending to power a small microcontroller off a coin cell battery. The microcontroller consumes as little as 15 microamps. I have a couple questions:

Just confirming, will the IC work with such low current draw on the output?
Again, confirming, will the IC accept low voltage when the battery is almost drained?
Can I use the given circuit configuration in the documentation for my function?
Do I need to change any passive components from the circuit given in the documentation for my use?

Thanks!

15 mA is a lot for a coin cell. Did you mean microamps?

Amateur, you are way over what you should be considering for a coin cell (most of them, anyway.) Way way over. And if you think 15 mA is "little" then you are looking in the wrong places for MCUs. We really need to know what order of magnitude is involved. If the magnitude is in the tens of mA, then you need another MCU. Go look for one. If the magnitude in in the tens of uA, then at least that's fine. But you need to clarify that fact then. And that is for a lithium-ion cell, not a lithium coin cell.

You're right, I made a mistake, it should be 15 microamps

That regulator seems to be intended for beefier battery cells. I think these kind of SEPIC regulators are mostly used for standard Li/Ion cells that go from 4V down towards 3V and you'd like a fixed 3.3V supply. Except yours seem suited for 5V out. How did you come up with this regulator? Do you really need 5V?

Also, alkaline or li/ion coin cell probably matters a lot here, since they have different voltage ranges.

I need 5V for the MCU I'm using. Is there another IC/method I can use to boost coin cell battery voltage to 5V that will allow low current draw on the output?

@AmateurEnthusiast Go to the 2nd edition (not the 3rd edition) of "The Art of Electronics" and find Figure 6.57 there. This is a true micropower circuit that fits your needs. Read the text there very carefully. But you will not find something like this in standard fare from IC manufacturers. So you will need to cobble it up, yourself.

First of all, that converter is not suitable for microamp-level loads. If you look at the efficiency curves, you can see that it is only 50% efficient at a load current of 2 mA, which tells you that its own consumption (when not in SHUTDOWN) is also on the order of 2 mA. If your MCU is only drawing 15 uA, then you'll be wasting about 99.3% of your battery energy in the converter!
Second, what is special about your 5 V MCU? There are many modern choices for low-power MCUs that can operate from far lower voltages, many at 3.0 - 3.3 V and some as low as 2 V. You should consider moving your application to one of those.
